# Absolute Value Inequality Implication

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, absolute-value

From my knowledge of the properties of absolute value inequalities, I'm failing to see why:

$$|f(x)-A|<1  \rightarrow |f(x)|<|A| + 1$$

The only approach I know is to split up the two possible cases:

$$ (1) :  f(x) - A> -1$$

and

$$(2) : f(x) - A < 1$$

So $f(x) < A+1$, but how does this imply $|f(x)|<|A| + 1$ ?

Comment: Triangle inequality: $$A + 1 \leq \vert A +1 \vert \leq \vert A \vert + 1$$

Comment: @bounceback Yes, but your comment doesn't address the issue that $f(x)$ may be negative, so $f(x) \leq B$ doesn't then imply $|f(x)|\leq B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The triangle inequality says $|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$. From this, setting $a=(x-y)$ and $b=y$, we get
$$|x| \leq |x-y|+|y|$$
from which we deduce
$$|x|-|y|\leq |x-y|.$$
This inequality gives you the result you want:
$$|f(x)|-|A| \leq |f(x)-A| \lt 1$$
so from $|f(x)|-|A| \lt 1$
you immediatly get
$$|f(x)|\lt |A|+1.$$
In fact, the following holds: try to verify it:
$$\Bigl| |x|-|y|\Bigr| \leq |x\pm y| \leq |x|+|y|.$$

Answer (score 1):

**More generally:** This is a consequence of the so-called [reverse triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality), itself a consequence of the triangle inequality:
$$
||x|-|y|| \leq |x-y|, \qquad x,y\in\mathbb{R} \tag{$\dagger$}
$$
Apply it to $f(x)$ and $A$ to get
$$
||f(x)|-|A|| \leq |f(x)-A|
$$
which implies $|f(x)|\leq |f(A)|+|f(x)-A|$.

---

*The reverse triangle inequality, very useful, is quite immediate given the triangle inequality: from
$$
|x| = |x-y+y|  \leq |x-y|+|y| 
$$
and
$$
|y| = |y-x+x|  \leq |x-y|+|x| 
$$
we get $||x|-|y||= \max( |x|-|y|, |y|-|x| ) \leq |x-y|$.*